# Trying to start the first WCF service

Tags: c#, .net, wcf, service

I am trying to start my first WCF service.

Well, I want to point out that I have fully understood the WCF architecture and pillars (ABC: Address Binding and Contract = Endpoint). Furthermore, I have understood many elements of the WCF philosophy, so, I am not exactly a mere newbye...

However, theory aside, real problems come when someone puts his hands on the real things...

I have these three files:

File `IService1.cs`

```
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.Linq;
using System.Runtime.Serialization;
using System.ServiceModel;
using System.Text;

/// <summary>
/// This is the interface that specifies contract for the Sevice1 of this service application.
/// In this file the interface is specified in order to set the service operations that can be invoked by requestors.
/// </summary>
namespace EchoWcfLibrary {
    /// <summary>
    /// The interface specifies for those classes implementing it (services), the operation that the service will expose.
    /// </summary>
    [ServiceContract]
    public interface IService1 {
        // This does not use serialization (implicit serialization in considered: base types used).
        [OperationContract]
        string GetData(int value);
        // This uses data contracts and serialization.
        [OperationContract]
        CompositeType GetDataUsingDataContract(CompositeType composite);
    }

    /// <summary>
    /// The following class defines data contract for those operations managing with non primitive types and, for this reason, needing serialization support (explicit, not implicit)
    /// </summary>
    [DataContract]
    public class CompositeType {
        // Members not serialized
        bool boolValue = true;
        string stringValue = "Hello ";
        // Serialized
        [DataMember]
        public bool BoolValue {
            get { return boolValue; }
            set { boolValue = value; }
        }
        // Serialized
        [DataMember]
        public string StringValue {
            get { return stringValue; }
            set { stringValue = value; }
        }
    }
}
```

File `Service1.cs`

```
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.Linq;
using System.Runtime.Serialization;
using System.ServiceModel;
using System.Text;

/// <summary>
/// This is the service host implementation. A class implementing the service is specified.
/// </summary>
namespace EchoWcfLibrary {
    /// <summary>
    /// This class implements the IService1 service.
    /// </summary>
    public class Service1 : IService1 {
        // One operation.
        public string GetData(int value) {
            return string.Format("You entered: {0}", value);
        }
        // The other operation.
        public CompositeType GetDataUsingDataContract(CompositeType composite) {
            if (composite == null) {
                throw new ArgumentNullException("composite");
            }
            if (composite.BoolValue) {
                composite.StringValue += "Suffix";
            }
            return composite;
        }
    }
}
```

These files, are placed inside a project called `EchoWcfLibrary`

And the main: `Program.cs`

```
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.Linq;
using System.Text;
using System.ServiceModel;
using EchoWcfLibrary;

namespace WcfServiceApplication {
    public static class Program {
        static void Main(string[] args) {
            // Setting endpoints and setting the service to start properly.
            // Base address specified: http://localhost:8080/service1
            using (ServiceHost host = new ServiceHost(typeof(Service1), new Uri("http://localhost:8080/service1"))) {
                host.AddServiceEndpoint(typeof(IService1), new BasicHttpBinding(), "svc");
                host.AddServiceEndpoint(typeof(IService1), new NetTcpBinding(), "net.tcp://localhost:8081/service1/tcpsvc");
                host.Open();
                System.Threading.Thread.Sleep(1000000);
                host.Close();
            }
        }
    }
}
```

This last file is in a separate project called `WcfServiceApplication`
The two projects exist in the same solution.
The `WcfServiceApplication` has, of course, a link to the other project.

I would like to start this service that, as you can see, is the one that Visual Studio puts in the WCF Library template.

Well, I tried to run it the first times and had some problems with http namespace reservations, I fixed it using netsh and adding explicit reservations for my user and for the specified http namespaces.

However what I encounter is the following: The WCF host application, which is a small application, very useful, shows the currently hosted services. There is just one service hosted: mine but its status is stopped, and it tells me, in the description box, that NO ENDPOINT has been defined!!!

But I defined them in `Program.cs`... I do not understand...
What am I doing wrong?

Thankyou

PS
Note that even defining `host.AddServiceEndpoint(typeof(IService1), new BasicHttpBinding(), "svc")` only (without the tcp endpoint) gives the same result....

One more thing: I understand that this approach in building a service is not very good... however, instead using auto-generating code tools I would like to understand, first, how to create and run a service from the roots, and then, how to do that with higher level tools... thank you

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The problem appears to be that you have defined two endpoints, 'svc' (http) and 'net.tcp://localhost:8081/service1/tcpsvc' (tcp), and then tried to start the service host using a third endpoint, which is not defined in either of the two endpoints you've configured.

I recommend removing the code that is programmatically creating the bindings, adding a .config file to your project, and then using the WCF Service Configuration Editor built into Visual Studio (as of 2008 onwards) to do the heavy-lifting for you.

Comment: Well I understand your recommends, and thank you for this but... I really hate letting an IDE do my work, or better at the beginning, I would like to know how to start a service from the grounds.... However... where is the third endpoint??? :) Thank you

Comment: In your code, you're asking WCF to create a service host based on this endpoint:

using (ServiceHost host = new ServiceHost(typeof(Service1), new Uri("http://localhost:8080/service1")))

In the service host's config, you've defined one http endpoint, as follows (with no base url): ) 

new BasicHttpBinding(), "svc");

Hope that makes sense.